# Is it possible to perform second order SQL injection with email addresses?

Tags: sql-injection, injection

Let's imagine a website which allows users to Sign up and login only with their email address.

Is it possible to perform a second order SQL injection in that case?

Answer (score 2):

It's possible to perform a SQL injection attack anywhere that the system places user defined data (in this case the username) directly into a SQL query without first sanitising it.

So, the answer to your question is yes, it is possible, depending on the behaviour of the system in question.

Comment: Yes but what if the application was only allowing emails as usernames?

Comment: @Mico Then the question becomes "How perfect is your email filter?".  Even valid email addresses could trigger SQL injection if it's directly injected.  For example, a dash is a perfectly valid email address character, but produces a comment in SQL.  Hence a double quote could be used in your example.

Comment: @Mico It has nothing to do with "what type of data is allowed" but with "how is all the allowed data sanitised".